# Cannot present scene with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I have two SKScene `SceneA`,`SceneB`.

I have implemented two methods(`willMoveFromView`,`didMoveToView`) in each scene.

Assume, I am currently in `SceneA` and i want to present `SceneB` via this code block:

```
SceneB *sceneB  = [SceneB sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
sceneB.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
[self.view presentScene:sceneB];
```

When I present this scene, I can see this:

```
sceneA willMoveFromView
sceneB didMoveToView
sceneA init
sceneB willMoveFromView
sceneA didMoveToView
```

And finally I return to first `SceneA` ! There is no other code that pushes `SceneA` from `SceneB` . I don't know what to do, please help

**UPDATE:**

As @LearnCocos2D says, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is forced every time I present scene
And I present sceneA in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` with following code

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
SKView* skView = (SKView*)self.view;
SceneA *sceneA = [SceneA sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
sceneA.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
[skView presentScene:sceneA];
}
```

Comment: My guess: you implemented presenting the first scene in viewWillLayoutSubviews but you are not testing whether the skView.scene property is nil. Presenting a new scene (as does rotating device) can trigger viewWillLayoutSubviews repeatedly.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D you are right! It forces viewWillLayoutSubviews again and again. But i don't know how to fix this, maybe I test not that I must. Please, answer my question and I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LearnCocos2D says,  `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is forced repeatedly , And I used to create new scene everytime it has been called. So I need to check if SKView.scene property is not nil. Here is the code:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
SKView* skView = (SKView*)self.view;
if(!skView.scene){
SceneA *sceneA = [SceneA sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
sceneA.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
[skView presentScene:sceneA];
}
}
```